# VBA Multi-Dimensional Arrays - Array Literal Syntax

Tags: vba, multidimensional-array

I want to create a multi-dimensional array where I assign all the values at once instead of going through all the array coordinate values one by one.  I believe this is called setting 'array literals'.  Anyway, all my variables are string values.  The code below doesn't give me a syntax error but when I step through  I'm getting a "Compile error: Can't assign to array" message on pkg= line.  How do I make this work?

```
Sub test_array2()

Dim pkg(2, 2) As String

pkg = [{"PRetail","Retail Packaged"};{"PFoodservice","Foodservice 
Packaged"}]

Debug.Print pkg(1, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a warning about doing this this way - the "identifier" (i.e. the part within the `[` ... `]`) is limited to 255 characters.  You get a "Identifier too long" syntax error if you exceed the limit.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign directly to an array like that, so you need to use a variant:

```
Sub test_array2()

    Dim pkg As Variant

    pkg = [{"PRetail","Retail Packaged";"PFoodservice","FoodservicePackaged "}]

    Debug.Print pkg(1, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: You can assign to a non-variant array, just not a fixed size one like `Dim pkg(2, 2)`. In this case the array also has to contain `Variant`s due to the return type of the `[]`, so the correct declaration would be `Dim pkg() As Variant`, at which point the difference with `Dim pkg As Variant` is a technicality.